# Не удаляется объект при связи @OneToMany Java Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Не могу понять в чем может быть ошибка при удалении

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`quizzes`.`question`, CONSTRAINT `FK_d96vtjbes71xkfbiwibobmopd` FOREIGN KEY (`id_quiz`) REFERENCES `quiz` (`id`))

В классе Quiz такие связи:

```
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Question> questions =new TreeSet();
```

В классе Question такие:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Answer> answer;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_quiz")
    private Quiz quiz;
```

В Answer:

```
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_question")
    private Question question;
```

Пробовал добавлять question в quiz двумя способами:(Ошибка в двух способах та же)

```
 Question question=new Question(titleQuiestion,answerList);
 quizService.getCurrentQuiz().getQuestions().add(question);
 serviceQuiz.update(quizService.getCurrentQuiz());
 // questionService.persist(question); //Второй способ, но при создании в конструкторе еще пишется владелец- в данном случае quizService.getCurrentQuiz()
```

Полагаю, что это происходит из-за смежной таблицы или из-за того, что не правильно использовал каскад в аннотациях. Но точно понять не могу, буду рад любой помощи!

Таким образом у меня происходит добавление

```
@Service
 abstract class HibServiceEntity<T, Id extends Serializable> {
 public void persist(T entity) {
        daoEntity.openCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
        daoEntity.persist(entity);
        daoEntity.closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
    }

@Controller
public class QuestionController {
     @RequestMapping(method=POST, value="questions/newquestion")
        public String postAddQuestion(Model model,
                                      @RequestParam("titileOfQuestion") String titleOfQuestion,
                                      @RequestParam("answers") String answerLine,
                                      @RequestParam("rightanswers") String rightAnswers){

            StringTokenizer tokzer=new StringTokenizer(answerLine, "\n");

            List<Answer> answerList=new ArrayList<>();
            while (tokzer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                answerList.add(new Answer(tokzer.nextToken().trim()));
            }
            tokzer=new StringTokenizer(rightAnswers, "\n");
            for (int i=0;tokzer.hasMoreTokens();i++) {
                answerList.get(i).setRight(Boolean.parseBoolean(tokzer.nextToken().trim()));
            }
            Question qu=new Question(titleOfQuestion,answerList);
            quizService.getCurrentQuiz().getQuestions().add(qu);
            quizServiceHib.update(quizService.getCurrentQuiz());

            return "redirect:/questions";
        }
```

Так происходит удаление:

```
 public void delete(T entity){
        getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
    }
    public List<T> findAll(){
        List<T> collection = (List<T>) getCurrentSession().createQuery("from "+getGenericType().getSimpleName()).list();
        return collection;
    }

@Controller
public class QuestionController {
    @RequestMapping(method = GET, value ="questions/removequestion/{id}")
        public String getRemoveQuestion(@PathVariable("id") int id){
            questionServiceHib.delete(id);
            return "redirect:/questions";
        }
```

Comment: Добавляются нормально?

Comment: посмотрите какой скл запрос генирирует hibernate.

Comment: @Bakhuss Да, добавляется хорошо. При удалении используется тот же алгоритм, что и по отношению один ко многим (пользователь к нескольким созданным опросами)

Comment: Код работоспособен:
 public void delete(Id id) {
        daoEntity.openCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
        T entity = (T) daoEntity.findById(id);
        daoEntity.delete(entity);
        daoEntity.closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
    }

  public void delete(T entity){
        getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
    }

Comment: @aleshka-batman 
delete from Question where id=10
Ошибка в следующем:
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`quizzes`.`quiz_question`, CONSTRAINT `FK_emaf1dh012y3vrjrl2nyxiphy` FOREIGN KEY (`questions_id`) REFERENCES `question` (`id`))

Comment: Можете в вопросе описать, как вы делаете удаление?

Comment: @RomanDanilov Да, давайте и добавление за одно. Мне кажется в этом причина

Answer (score 1):

1. меняем тип EAGER на LAZY
2. встраиваем фильтр OpenInViewEntityManager
3. уберите JoinColum, хибер сам поймет как ему нужно вытягивать данные
4. организовывайте работу через JPARepository
5. удаление и добавление элементов производите так же как и в случаи с коллекциями и если у Вас не statles приложение то достаточно будет вызвать для обновления сущности в базе repository.save(entity)

P.S. снесите полностью реализацию работы с сессиями и транзакциями, предоставьте все это ORM и репозиториям, имхо удобно

Comment: попробую разобраться в вышесказанном. 
К сожалению мне реализации работы с сессиями необходимы в рамках проходимого курса для более-глубокого понимания работы, поэтому убрать их не получится.

Comment: Странно то, что удаление Quiz (опроса) у которого тоже есть OneToMany и ManyToOne осуществляется без проблем. А вот удаление Question(Вопроса), который состоит в Quiz и имеет свои собственные ответы- нет

Comment: Хибер не поймет, как вытаскивать без JoinColumn, потому что имя филда нестандартное

Comment: @Roman Danilov, а вы возьмите да посмотрите сами на результат

Comment: @Roman Danilov что значит "не стандартное"? Каким должно быть?