# Не работает автоинкремент от Hibernate, используя Spring @ModelAttribute

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, spring-mvc

Почему не происходит автоинкремент объекта, при использовании Spring MVC аннотации для создания объектов из заданных данных в спринг-форме.

```
@ModelAttribute("userReg") User user
```

user- инициализируется данными, которые задал для него в спринг-форме userReg, а автоинкремент id-шника по-сути должен происходить автоматически, но нет.
Почему так происходит?

```
class User {
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Comment: Ну вы же из формы его достаете и при этом нужно явно указывать ему setId или копировать данные для работы с сущностью, ибо как таковой User является DTO(POJO), но никак не сущностью

Comment: @GenCloud, Спасибо за информацию. Со спрингом и хибернейтом столкнулся относительно-недавно, буду знать.
Перепишите в ответ- к завтрашнему дню если это будет единственным решением- отмечу как верное

Comment: @GenCloud, может Вы знаете, почему может быть подобное?
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/843347/Не-удаляется-объект-при-связи-onetomany-java-hibernate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вы же из формы его достаете и при этом нужно явно указывать ему setId или копировать данные для работы с сущностью, ибо как таковой User является DTO(POJO), но никак не сущностью

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось всё намного проще, чем я думал. 
Для id - использовал примитивный тип int, который при возвращении из формы имел значение id=0. Как оказалось, необходимо int поменять на объект-оболочку Integer, который в следствии вернет null. После полученого объекта из формы- хибернейт вместо null подставляет свой автоинкремент.